# Why is Excel butchering my Conditional Formatting?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I  have this conditional formatting set

[image]

but when I move/delete/copy/cut/paste/insert a cell/row/column my conditional formatting becomes like this

[image]

The rules have duplicated themselves, the "Applies to" now is broken up and from the little bit you can see one of my blue rules has an altered Rule.

Sometimes I make mistakes when making an Excel spreadsheet requiring me to move and or delete stuff from a single cell to entire rows. Why does Excel think it's necessary to butcher my conditional formatting ? Especially since by creating these duplicate rules it gives me more work to do if I need to refine them later on which is what I use conditional formatting to avoid doing i.e. more work

Comment: FWIW, I've just did some basic testing in my Excel 2016, and no matter how I copy/pasted, inserted, or deleted, my range stayed "=$A:$D", except when I inserted or deleted a column within my range, and then it just expanded or contracted my range as expected.  As with most weird app behaviour, I have to ask if you have all the latest service packs and Office updates installed?

Comment: @DarkMoon well my PC is Windows 7 SP1 and Windows Update does say it's all up to date (Excel points me to Windows Update when i go File > Help > Check for Updates) so i would assume it's all up to date. as i have tagged 2010 it could be sometime between after 2010 and 2016 versions of Office this was fixed up as being a bug

Comment: Yeah, I was more pointing out that that behaviour isn't happening for me, so it's not "by design".  :-P  Hence the question about updates.  When you're in the Windows Update screen, there should be an option to enable "updates for other Microsoft products", which is off by default in Win7; have you enabled that?  If not, you won't see Office updates in Windows Update.  One other thought; can you reproduce this behaviour in a new workbook?  Might be something wrong within the file rather than Excel itself?

Comment: What's in lines 73-74? What happens if you delete lines 73-74 before performing the operations that cause the rules to change?

Comment: @DarkMoon *"Give me updates for Microsoft products and check for new option Microsoft software when i update windows"* is on, this is a work PC so i assume it was enabled. as for new workbook i assume you mean new file and yes i tried that, aside from that the file the screenshots was a new file created only a couple of days ago i started a new book, created a simple single rule and did some cutting, pasting, moving, deleting it did the same thing (albeit different cells refences)

Comment: @techraf well in the new book i started ^ when the same thing happened but with different cell values, the rule which represented what the second blue rule in my screenshots shows (the one which applied to `$D$74`) when i deleted the row the rule just disappeared. i would assume it would be the same for the original speadsheet i took screenshots (i undid the changes until the rules were restored and manually deleted data inside cells and retyped to avoid the butchering)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel conditional formatting fragmentation](https://superuser.com/questions/598368/excel-conditional-formatting-fragmentation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preserve conditional formatting on cut-paste](https://superuser.com/questions/649675/preserve-conditional-formatting-on-cut-paste)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens when you Cut/Copy and then Paste lines within the applied range, in Excel 2000, 2003, 2007, and 2010 (I don't know about others).

it is still fully functional; if you consider then first and fifth line shown, they together define the complete range (just stupidly split), and the formula is identical for both (note that each formula is shown relative to the first cell it applies to; as the formula in the fifth line applies to $D$74, it contains ...$D$74... in it).

I have not found a way (looking for several years) to change that behavior. Whenever you copy or cut and then insert lines several times, Excel cuts the respective conditional formulas' *ranges* in pieces like this.

A manual workaround (to repair the formulas) is to

1. Select all lines except the first, chose  'Clear Rules from Selected Cells'. You will now have your conditional formatting only in the first line.
2. Open the Conditional Formatting manager, chose 'This worksheet', and extend all formulas to all lines (by typing `:$nnnn` over `:$2`).
3. Yes you will have to repeat that ever so often. As I said, I have not found a better solution in years.

Comment: "it is still fully functional" - unfortunately not. I've the same issue with a pivot table, upon filter changes rules disappear from the range of the table. However thanks for the tip

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/a/991431/79488

Comment: There are still dozens of rules listed even after doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same trouble. My spreadsheet is a spending tracker and I have about 25 different formatting rules based on spending categories. Sometimes my formatting rules blow out to nearly 200 with numerous duplications of my original rules.

The quickest work around I have found to clear all the unneccessary rules is to create a template worksheet first which contains "clean & correct" formatting rules only.

Then in the offending worksheet I go to the Home tab > Conditional Formatting > Clear Rules > Clear Rules from Entire Sheet.

Back to the template worksheet, select the entire worksheet, click on the Format Painter.

Switch to the cleared worksheet and paste/paint into cell A1.

The reason your formula has split itself like that is because you likely/probably/possibly inserted new lines at rows 73 and 74 and so the formatting isn't applied there. The formula then picks up at row 75 and continues until the extreme edge of the worksheet (row 1,048,576).

If you set up a template where the formatting is $A:$D and then follow my steps above to clean and reapply your styles, it should work correctly.
Hope that helps you after all these years!

Answer (score 0):

And this still happens on browser-based Excel. In fact, this should be considered as a bug, as this makes a mess on existing conditional format.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1237577)