# Fade out Excel cells with errors without using conditional formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

Is there a way to fade out cells that have errors that doesn't require using conditional formatting?

I have been unable to fix an issue that causes hundreds to thousands of duplicated rules (see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1113555/why-is-excel-butchering-my-conditional-formatting)) so I'm looking for a way to do at least some of my formatting without rules

[image]

Comment: you can run vba in a Worksheet_Calculate event that loops through the cells and does the formatting.

Comment: or you can wrap the formula in `=IFERROR(...,"")` and instead of Errors the cell will appear blank.

Comment: IIRC, I had these specific ones return N/A because `""` isn't truly blank so it was messing up charts

Comment: Yes, it seems that the VBA code is a good method.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much simpler to make one conditional formatting rule to fade any cell that is error, such as

```
=IF(ISERROR(A1),)
```

and [apply it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7f5b.png) to $A:$XFD, so I'm not sure why you don't want to do that. Maybe there is more to your question then you are supplying.